# grails 4 sessionRegistry empty

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-4

Upgrading to grails 4, sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipal() is always empty.

The original spring bean in resources.groovy were

```
sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)
concurrentSessionFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter){
    sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry
    expiredUrl = '/login'
}
```

As this was no longer working I tried updating resources.groovy to

```
sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl) 
registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy(RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy, ref(sessionRegistry))
sessionFixationProtectionStrategy(SessionFixationProtectionStrategy)
concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy, ref(sessionRegistry)){
    maximumSessions=1
    exceptionIfMaximumExceeded=true
}
compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy,
    [ref(registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy),ref(sessionFixationProtectionStrategy),ref(concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy)])
```

All of those beans are from the org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session package.

I've added names to grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames as well

The DaoAuthenticationProvider is extended by a custom auth provider. Login and logout works fine, but the principals never get registered in the upgraded app. Do I need register them manually (sessionRegistry.registerNewSession())?

There are old answers that say to use grails install-templates and then edit the web.xml in src/templates/war. However in grails 4, install-templates didn't generate war/web.xml

I tried adding it a /WEB-INF/web.xml, but still no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing the sessionAuthenticationStragegy bean definition, try removing the compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy line and replace it with:

`sessionAuthenticationStrategy(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy, [ref('concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy'), ref('sessionFixationProtectionStrategy'), ref('registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy')])`

This is the only difference I see between your code and mine, which is working with Grails 4.